# Как написать текст на новой строке JLabel(java)

Tags: java, строки

У меня есть такая строчка.

```java
label.setText(label.getText()+igf+"."+marks[igf][0]+" | "+marks[igf][1]+" | "+marks[igf][2]);
```

Все работает, но я не знаю как сделать, чтобы эта строчка писалась на новой строчке.`\n` не помогает.

Comment: А ещё. Как на этом сайте писать код в вопросе?

Comment: При добавлении/редактировании вопроса есть панель с набором инструментов. Там и находится "Пример кода". Или же, как в вашем случае, достаточно взять в кавычки " ` " [клавиша "~" или же "ё"]

Comment: @KotFind а еще проще выделить участок с кодом и нажать `ctrl+K`. Если вы с десктопной версии, разумеется :)

Answer (score 1):

`JLabel` понимает `html`. Следовательно можно ему передать что то вроде:

```
label.setText("<html>Строка1<br>Строка2</html>");
```

Описание тега `br` [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/br)

**UPD:**

К вопросу, "Как добавлять надписи в label в цикле, каждый раз с новой строки, при этом возможности сформировать сразу весь текст нет".

Что то вы странное изобретаете, но пожалуйста:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("<html>Line 1</html>");

// где то позже в коде:

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   String currentText = label.getText();
   // строка, без закрывающего тега </html>
   String newText = currentText.substring(0, curentText.length()-7); 
   label.setText(newText + "<br>New Line " + i + "</html>");
}
```

**UPD2:**

Работающий пример:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();                        
        label.setText("<html>Str1</html>");

        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String currentText = label.getText();
            String newText = currentText.substring(0, currentText.length()-7);
            label.setText(newText + "<br>New Line " + i + "</html>");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: А не подскажешь как сделать если у меня эта строка в цикле? И одна команда пишет только одну строку. А при следующем выполнении ещё одну и т.д.

Comment: Вариант сначала сформировать строку полного наименования, а после уже ее установить не рассматривается?

Comment: Нет не получится.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Не работает. Вообще ничего не пишет.

Comment: Что то не так делаете. Добавил в ответ работающий пример, выводящий фрейм на экран и дополняющий текст способом, который я вам предложил.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что ошибка в этой строчке 
label.setText(newText + "<br>"+igf+"."+marks[igf][0]+" | "+marks[igf][1]+" | "+marks[igf][2]+ "</html>");